# Stereo vision with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d

can anyone provide a good sample program on OpenCV depth maps or distance calculation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In OpenCV's `samples/cpp` folder there is a sample program called `stereo_match.cpp`.