# Generating 3D (x,y,z) Point Clouds from Two 2D Stereo Images

Tags: python, c++, matlab, image-processing

I've been trying to read through the Stackoverflow questions for generating point clouds (x,y,z) coordinates from a left and right stereo image pair.

I haven't come to any definite solution, and I'm asking the community here for some help.

***Problem statement:*** ***Given two stereo images, generate 3D (x,y,z) cartesian coordinate point clouds from those and do so in a way that lends itself to completing this point-cloud generation in a way that could work over a large set (thousands) of pairs of stereo images***

My programming language experience lends itself to MATLAB, but I've dabbled in Python, and C++ is limited, but I may be able to work in that as well.

**Speed is a factor here, so the the idea is to find a quick method of successively going through these pairs and generating the point cloud.**

NOTE: I am not asking for the BEST as to avoid comparative solutions, I'm just asking for solutions.

Thank you very much!

Edit: After being recommended to utilize the Stereo Block Matching implementation in OpenCV, I may steer away from this method, as there is a wide variation in regards to texture of the topographical pictures that I'm dealing with.

Comment: Have you looked at OpenCV? A better pointer could be found in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893619/stereo-vision-with-opencv

Comment: I have, but as it is robust I'm not aware of all of the features, I'll look at this right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is called "Stereo Block Matching".  If you don't feel like writing it yourself, OpenCV has [an implementation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereobm) ready to go (even a [CUDA accelerated version](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/cudastereo/doc/stereo.html)).

Comment: After doing some light reading on Stereo Block Matching and block matching variations, is this a really good way to get even quasi-accurate point clouds? With a wide variance of textures present in the topography that I'm looking at, I don't know if this would be the answer.